# Colunas não alinham dentro do row

Tags: html, css, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando alinhar uma grid da seguinte forma:
3 colunas x N linhas

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 150px;">
  @forelse($models as $model)
    <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left: 5px;">
      <div class="row card">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="col-md-12 card-img"
              style="background-image: url(''); background-size: 100% 100%;">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 card-container">
              <h4 class="text-center"><b>{{$model->name}}</b></h4> 
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  @empty
    <h2>Não existe modelos cadastrados ainda.</h2>
  @endforelse
</div>
```

Todo esse código está dentro de uma div pai `<div class="container"></div>`

Porém, o resultado que ele está me retornando é esse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que como estou usando o `col-md-4` dentro de uma row que é `col-md-12` o certo seria se ele tivesse 3 cards em cada linha e centralizasse.

Mais informações:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Alguma ideia de onde posso estar errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu grid está montado de forma equivocada, é `col` dentro de `col`, `row` desnecessária etc. Tente simplificar as coisas.

Sua estrutura básica deve ser:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
```

Montei esse modelo retirando umas classes desnecessárias e acho que vai ficar mo vc deseja.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 150px;">

            <div class="col-md-4" style="">
                <div class="card">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="card-img" style="background: red; background-size: 100% 100%;">
                        </div>
                        img
                        <div class="card-container">
                            <h4 class="text-center"><b>{{$model->name}}</b></h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="">
                <div class="card">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="card-img" style="background: red; background-size: 100% 100%;">
                        </div>
                        img
                        <div class="card-container">
                            <h4 class="text-center"><b>{{$model->name}}</b></h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="">
                <div class="card">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="card-img" style="background: red; background-size: 100% 100%;">
                        </div>
                        img
                        <div class="card-container">
                            <h4 class="text-center"><b>{{$model->name}}</b></h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h2>Não existe modelos cadastrados ainda.</h2>

        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>
```